# Deleting a row using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete a row from a table in my database but I keep getting a `null reference exception`.

I know that the code I wrote isn't grabbing the ID number from the `ComboBox` but I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code I have:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //select row to delete
        Doctor del = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
        Doctor deleted = (from d in MainWindow.nlh.Doctors
                          where d.DoctorID == del.DoctorID
                          select d).First();
        //delete row from db
        MainWindow.nlh.Doctors.DeleteObject(deleted);
        //Save to database
        MainWindow.nlh.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Doctor deleted");
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code used to fill the combobox:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cbDocIdd.DataContext = MainWindow.nlh.Doctors;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the doctor with this id exist.

Comment: yes. the combobox is populated from the database.

Comment: So *where* does this NRE occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.FirstOrDefault` and **check** whether a valid entity has been found:

```
//select row to delete
Doctor del = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
Doctor deleted = (from d in MainWindow.nlh.Doctors
                  where d.DoctorID == del.DoctorID
                  select d).FirstOrDefault();

// check if it even exists!!
if(deleted != null) 
{ 
    //delete row from db
    MainWindow.nlh.Doctors.DeleteObject(deleted);
    //Save to database
    MainWindow.nlh.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Doctor deleted");
    this.Close();
}
```

If you use `.First()` and the doctor with that given ID doesn't exist, you'll get an exception

Also: make sure the `del` value is OK and **not null** before using it in the following statement. Same goes for `MainWindow` - are you sure this is not null ??

**Update:** can you try these two lines and tell me what the result is??

```
//select row to delete
object selectedObj = cbDocIdd.SelectedItem;

if(selectedObj != null)
{
    string typeOfSelectedObj = selectedObj.GetType().Name;
}

Doctor del = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
```

Is `selectedObj` something other than null?? And if so: what **type** is it??

**Update #2:** Ok - so the doctor does exist and is being returned OK - can you try this for me??

Replace this line:

```
Doctor del = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
```

with this instead:

```
Doctor del = cbDocIdd.SelectedItem as Doctor;
```

When you run this - is `del` now something other than `null` ?

**Solution:**

In the end, the *real* reason why this code broke lies in the fact that the call to `MainWindow.nlh.Doctors.DeleteObject(deleted);` caused an event handler to fire, which included this code:

```
private void cbDocIdd_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // populate with DoctorID from db
    Doctor deletedDoc = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
    tbLastName.Text = deletedDoc.LastName.ToString();
    tbFirstName.Text = deletedDoc.FirstName.ToString();
    tbLicenseNumber.Text = deletedDoc.LicenseNumber.ToString();
}
```

but in this situation, when a doctor is being deleted, the `deletedDoc` was returned as `NULL`, but no check is in place to ensure to access only a **non-NULL** object ..... therefore, an infamous "null-reference exception" was thrown when trying to access the `deletedDoc.LastName` property...

Comment: I've tried it with .FirstOrDefault() and it's not helping because the ID does exist (this is a school project and the combobox is populated straight from the db, with only valid IDs). del comes back null but i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is how it's filled:

Comment: private void cbDocIdd_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //populate with DoctorID from db
            Doctor deletedDoc = ((Doctor)cbDocIdd.SelectedItem);
            tbLastName.Text = deletedDoc.LastName.ToString();
            tbFirstName.Text = deletedDoc.FirstName.ToString();
            tbLicenseNumber.Text = deletedDoc.LicenseNumber.ToString();
        }

Comment: Ok if I'm reading this right, selectedobj shows the right doctor but the type says null. Not sure if that makes sense, as i said, i'm very new at this.

Comment: oh wait, sorry, the type says Doctor

Comment: Boy, if only we (or better: the OP) would have known the line that threw the exception! You're a terrier Marc!

Answer (score 0):

"null reference exception" shows when you try to use a method that is containing null value.

Such as if product have null value or assigned to null like product=null then you cannot use method as `product.count()` or something because `null.count()` is not supported.

```
    Doctor deleted = (from d in MainWindow.nlh.Doctors
                      where d.DoctorID == del.DoctorID
                      select d).FirstOrDefault(); 

use this and check null.
```